# Некорректно работают запросы в denver (PhpMyAdmin)

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

[Скрин_1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/14Rea.jpg)
[Скрин_2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4523Y.jpg)

На скриншотах -  результаты по одному и тому же запросу к базе данных (пока не разобрался,  как крепить сюда БД). 
На одном из них -  компьютер друга,  на втором - мой. 
Базы данных абсолютно одинаковы. 
Кодировки совпадают (utf8_general_ci). 
Denver одной и той же версии (он мне ехе-шник скидывал). 
Операционка на обоих компах - win 10 (разве что у меня корпоративная).

Но при всем при этом у него запросы работают корректно и выдают результат,  а у меня возвращают пустые строки. 
В чем может быть загвоздка?

P.S: Установил на еще один ноут. Тоже все работает без нареканий.  Так и не пойму,  почему на нормальной современной машине (MSI PE60 2QE) все идет наперекосяк